# Apply haldclut color to Image

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I am trying to do [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#hald-clut) in C# in ImageMagick.

I have a bitmap image and I have to apply a Hald CLUT image to the bitmap.

There is an example in the link in which they apply different hald CLUT to Rose Image and get the rose in different color.

How can I do this in C# and what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest you post this question to https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=27

Answer (score 0):

I do not use C#, but checkout

https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/Source/Magick.NET.Native/MagickImage.c

```
MAGICK_NET_EXPORT void MagickImage_HaldClut(Image *instance, const Image *image, ExceptionInfo **exception)
{
  MAGICK_NET_GET_EXCEPTION;
  HaldClutImage(instance, image, exceptionInfo);
  MAGICK_NET_SET_EXCEPTION;
}
```